# How to maintain browser compatability with Gradient in css?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am developing a website using html , css and javascript . The buttons display differently in every browser . Here are the screenshots for different browser of the same page :

Internet Explorer :
[image]

Firefox :
[image]

I actually intend it to display as it displays in firefox . Here Some of the css code i am using :

```
#button{
float: left;
width: 500px;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
background-color: #06C;
padding-left: 20px;

-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2), inset 0px 1px 1px 0px rgb(0,0,0);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2), inset 0px 1px 1px 0px rgb(0,0,0);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2), inset 0px 1px 1px 0px rgb(0,0,0);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0, #60B842),
    color-stop(0.85, #7FD13D)
);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    /* change these to change the button colors */
    #B58515 0%,
    #DC9E1F 85%
);

/* change this to change the text color and font type */
color:#fff;
font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:17px;
font-weight:bold;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #4c9434;
    }

    #button:hover{
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0, #6DD14B),
    color-stop(0.85, #85DB40)
);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    /* change these colors to change the mouse hover colors */
    #E17100 0%,
    #FF9326 85%
);
box-shadow:0 2px 0 #5EA839;
    }
```

There maybe some issues with using the gradient . Can someone suggest me any changes or another ways to code so that the webpage looks the same in different browsers ?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [Colorzilla's Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to generate cross browser CSS gradient code.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `-webkit-gradient()` and `-moz-gradient()` you also need to use the prefixes for IE and other browsers.

Example:

```
#linearBg2 {
  /* fallback */
  background-color: #1a82f7;
  background: url(images/linear_bg_2.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;

  /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1a82f7), to(#2F2727));

  /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

  /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

  /* IE 10 */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
}
```

[Source](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/)

[Read more here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/)

[Note that IE 9 and earlier do not support gradient](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient).

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that IE ignores your gradient css completely. You have to add a 'filter' in order for the gradient to appear in IE.

[This page](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient) will help you create a cross-browser gradient.

Answer (score 0):

All browser Support gradient property 
use this

```
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white, #1a82f7);/*Mozila*/
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, white, #1a82f7); /*opera*/
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white, #1a82f7);/*Chrome and safari*/
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='white',    EndColorStr='#1a82f7'); /*IE*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a set of CSS gradients that will be useful for you for cross-browser compatibility:

```
/* IE10 Consumer Preview */
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* Opera */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #00A3EF));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);
```